# Communities as a whole or a community as a whole

Tags: grammar

Let's say you are describing the benefits of a healthy family relationship.

> if every person had a healthy family relationship, this would yield a positive impact not only on every person, but also on **communities** as a whole.

Or

> if every person had a healthy family relationship, this would yield a positive impact not only on every person, but also on **a community** as a whole.

Which is grammatical or appropriate?

Comment: as long as your intend is to define a larger group of people being affected here you can say **"but also on larger communities as a whole"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if every person had a healthy family relationship, this would yield a positive impact not only on every person, but also on communities as a whole.

and

> if every person had a healthy family relationship, this would yield a positive impact not only on every person, but also on a community as a whole.

are both grammatically correct, however

> if every person had a healthy family relationship, this would yield a positive impact not only on every person, but also on **the community** as a whole.

where **the community** is the people of the earth.

Comment: Nice, thx. Spot on.

Answer (score 2):

They are both grammatical and appropriate, but with different meanings.

In your **second** example, the focus is on only one community, with the potential implication that other communities might not have similar benefits.

In contrast, in your **first** example, the benefits apply generally to communities:

- basic communities, made of individuals and families;
- communities of communities.

As an exception (perhaps forcing the meaning a little), we can see a family as a community too.